# How to add a VBA code to remove duplicates from excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've 2 sheets, for example (sheet 1 and 2). I'll copy some data from sheet 2 to sheet 1.

After that i need to remove duplicated values from a column.

My code is:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim excel As excel.Application
    Dim wb As excel.Workbook
    Dim sht As excel.Worksheet
    Dim f As Object

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    f.Show

    Set excel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
    Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f.SelectedItems(1))
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Query1")
```

'(((((select sheet 2)))))

```
    sht.Activate
    sht.Columns("A:D").Copy '(((((copy from sheet2))))
    Range("I5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues '(((((paste in sheet1))))

    sht.Activate
    sht.Columns("F:H").Copy '(((((copy from sheet2))))
    Range("Q5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  '(((((paste in sheet1))))

    wb.Close

End Sub
```

I need to know the code and location to remove the duplicated values from the **column B - sheet1** for example.

thks

Comment: I've tried to insert this piece of code:

[ActiveSheet.Range(range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo]

but didn't work.

Comment: Try Sheets(1).Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo. Note : There should not be any empty cells between these.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.
`Sheets(1).Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo.`

Comment: works well... but i need to remove duplicate values and the positions of remaining values are not changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the overall file to be the same (duplicate values are removed, but the positions of remaining values are not changed) then this code will work:

Note: you will need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime to use the dictionary object

```
Sub removeDuplicatesFromColumn(columnIndex As Integer)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim columnValues As Dictionary
    Set columnValues = New Dictionary

    'I've set this up backwards in case you want to remove rows/cells that are duplicates
    For rowIndex = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If columnValues.Exists(Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value) Then
            Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value = ""
        Else
            columnValues.Add Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value, ""
        End If
    Next rowIndex

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    'resume
End Sub
```

Comment: This code didn't remove duplicated values, just clear the content of specific cell's.

But ("duplicate values are removed, but the positions of remaining values are not changed") is exactly what i need.

Comment: what do you mean by remove duplicate values then? To me, setting a cell's value for null is a synonym to removing it

Comment: I've solved this question with the following code:

[Sub DeleteDuplicates()
  With Range("M5:M" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 4)
    .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(I$5:I5,I5)=1,1,"""")"
    .SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlTextValues).Offset(, -4).ClearContents
    .ClearContents
  End With
End Sub]